# How to automatically store screenshots to OneDrive?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-screenshots-to-onedrive-automatically-d04df71c-1cb0-4ad6-9f9c-b08494d79d6a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), there should be an option to store screenshots to OneDrive:

[image]

Unfortunately, on my 64-bit German Windows 10 PC (having both a personal and an Office 365 OneDrive linked), the dialog looks like this:

[image]

("Photos and videos" option missing, as well as the "Screenshots").

I am using OneDrive Version 2019 (Build 19.192.0926.0012).

**My question:**

Is there any option to still be able to let OneDrive on Windows 10 automatically save screenshots?

Comment: Everything looks like there is old OneDrive client/handler version, or OneDrive is not properly installed/configured. Check.

Comment: Thanks, @Akina, I've set the ["Insider Preview" checkbox](https://i.imgur.com/zNoKVQ3.png), waited some minutes, and now, I actually [_do_ have the option](https://i.imgur.com/kCRqcJi.png).

Comment: Funny enough, the optin disappeared again. I now have the initial option as the screenshot in my question shows.